# EF7 adding entity with relation in different context

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I use EntityFramework 7 in UWP application (EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite).
Microsoft recommends using a new context whenever there are requests to perform on the database to increase performance. Howerver I have an issue when I want to add a new element with an existing relationship in different contexts.
For example, I have a class Person and class Dog. A person has many dogs and a dog has only one owner.
In my case, I want to add a new Dog who has an existing person as owner.

Also, I want to create an abstraction layer to separate data access from my ViewModels.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}    

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public Dog(string name, Person person)
    {
        Name = name;
        Person = person;
    }
}
```

And my use case can be illustrated by the following code:

```
Person person = new Person() { Name = "Samuel" };
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.People.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    Dog dog = new Dog("Droopy", person);
    db.Dogs.Add(dog);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I execute this code, EF will create a new instance of Person in the database.
A workaround is to replace the Dog constructor by the following code:

```
public Dog(string name, Person person)
{
    Name = name;
    PersonId = person.PersonId;
}
```

But what is the best (and other) solution to solve my issue?

Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything you want in a single database call:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var person = db.Persons.Single(p => p.PersonId == personId);  // Tracks your person
    person.Dogs.Add(new Dog("Droopy"));
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve.
It's a possibility. But this requires a little more code in my abstraction layer. But I don't see an other solution

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's better for performance than to have one context for all

Comment: Yes, much better. One database call versus two plus you are only newing up and disposing once. Every call to SaveChanges() calls the database so minimize those.

Comment: Okay thank you again for your help.
Last question before validating this answer, how to load related entities with EF7? It seems Lazy loading no longer exists and the Include method no longer exists either.

Comment: Include/ThenInclude should still work in EF Core. Do you have a reference to the extension lib: using Microsoft.Data.Entity

Comment: It seeems Microsoft.Data.Entity is not in EF Core.
I use the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools packages and I don't have this namespace. I tried to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core and the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore packages but it is the same.

Comment: Okay, I retrieved the Include method. Finally it works with the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package but my project needed a cleanning.
Thanks for your help Steve.